# How to make calls to sdn.sitecore.net startpage.aspx over HTTPS?

Tags: configuration, login

I noticed that when I access the login page, the Edge browser logs that `HTTPS security is compromised`.

[image: Error]

Is there a way to change the url to HTTPS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can update the `Login.SitecoreUrl` config setting to point to an https url, the login page uses this setting as the src of the iframe:

```
<configuration xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Login.SitecoreUrl" set:value="https://sdn.sitecore.net/startpage.aspx"/>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You're my hero @jammykam!